# How to get slot to work inside a Quasar Layout

Tags: vuejs2, vue-router, quasar-framework

So I have a basic layout :

```html
<template>
    <q-layout view="lHh Lpr lFf">
        <q-header elevated class="bg-secondary text-white">
            <q-toolbar >              
                <slot name="toolbar"></slot>
            </q-toolbar>
        </q-header>
        <q-page-container >
            <router-view ></router-view>
        </q-page-container>
    </q-layout>
</template>
```

And a basic router:

```js
const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    component: () => import('layouts/MyLayout.vue'),
    children: [
      { path: '', component: () => import('pages/Index.vue') }
    ]
  }
]
```

and Index.vue:

```html
<template>
    <q-page>
       <template v-slot:default> CONTENT SHOWS</template>
       <template v-slot:toolbar> CONTENT DOESN'T SHOW</template>
    </q-page>
</template>
```

What do I do wrong? How can I get the slot up the router?

Comment: @aviboy2006: did you ever solve this?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: I was looking for exactly the same separation of concerns. It feels to me that QLayout does exist to solve scroll jump / orientation change problems on mobile, and has to be integrated with Vue Router in order to work. IMO all these overlay header and footer and panel things must be provided from pages (and subpages!), and slots are the most reasonable way to drop them where they should be. Silly to keep them in a "wrapper."

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer: there is no way to accomplish that using slots.

You are seeing `CONTENT SHOW` because `q-page` has the `default` slot, but there is no definition for the `toolbar` slot there. Remember, slots get passed to their direct parents, this is a Vue fundamental rule. Your practice moved me to the age of master pages.

Using [Name Views](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/named-views.html) is the proper solution -- should move your toolbars into separate components and define them in routes.

Another solution, check the current route and render a proper toolbar:

```
<template>
  <q-layout view="lHh Lpr lFf">
    <q-header elevated class="bg-secondary text-white">
      <q-toolbar>
        <template v-if="$route.name === 'Index'">
          <div>Toolbar for Index Page </div>
        </template>
        <template v-else-if="$route.fullPath.startsWith('/nested')">
          <div>Toolbar for Index2 Page </div>
        </template>
        <template v-else>
          <div>Toolbar for Default Pages </div>
        </template>
      </q-toolbar>
    </q-header>
    <q-page-container>
      <router-view></router-view>
    </q-page-container>
  </q-layout>
</template>
```

Of course, moving these `v-if` logics into a separate component is a better practice.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a long time since the original post, but maybe it can help someone else. Use *names* in *router-view*.

```html
<template>
    <q-layout view="lHh Lpr lFf">
        <q-header elevated class="bg-secondary text-white">
            <q-toolbar >              
                <router-view name="toolbar"></router-view>
            </q-toolbar>
        </q-header>
        <q-page-container >
            <router-view></router-view>
        </q-page-container>
    </q-layout>
</template>
```

Then, the route setup can contains something like this

```js
const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    component: () => import('layouts/MyLayout.vue'),
    children: [{ 
         path: '', 
         components : {
             default: () => import('pages/Index.vue'),
             toolbar: () => import('some another page or component.vue')
         }
    }]
  }
]
```